# JSpinner time constraint

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jspinner

I am trying to create a spinner that has hours and minutes. The minutes part needs to increment by 10 mins only and the time must range from the current time to an end time. I also need the minimum value (previously current time) to update to current time.

I tried playing around with it, but I just couldn't get it to work.

```
JSpinner spinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
    SpinnerDateModel spinnermodel = new SpinnerDateModel();
    spinnermodel.setCalendarField(Calendar.MINUTE);
    spinner1.setModel(spinnermodel);
    spinner1.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner1, "hh:mm"));

SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerDateModel(currentDate, currentDate, latestDate, Calendar.MINUTE * 10 ?);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `SpinnerDateModel` just uses 1 to increment the field you want to change.

I extended the `SpinnerDateModel` to add an addition property to the model to control the increment value instead of hard coding to 1:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MySpinnerDateModel extends SpinnerDateModel
{
    private int increment = 1;

    public MySpinnerDateModel(Date value, Comparable start, Comparable end, int calendarField)
    {
        super(value, start, end, calendarField);
    }

    public MySpinnerDateModel()
    {
        this(new Date(), null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }

    public void setIncrement(int increment)
    {
        this.increment = increment;
    }

    public int getIncrement()
    {
        return increment;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNextValue()
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date value = (Date)getValue();
        cal.setTime(value);
        cal.add(getCalendarField(), increment);
        Date next = cal.getTime();
        Comparable end = getEnd();

        return ((end == null) || (end.compareTo(next) >= 0)) ? next : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPreviousValue()
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date value = (Date)getValue();
        cal.setTime(value);
        cal.add(getCalendarField(), -increment);
        Date prev = cal.getTime();
        Comparable start = getStart();

        return ((start == null) || (start.compareTo(prev) <= 0)) ? prev : null;
    }
}
```

You should be able to use the model the way you did before but with one additional statement:

```
MySpinnerDateModel model = new MySpinnerDateModel(currentDate, currentDate, latestDate, Calendar.MINUTE); 
model.setIncrement( 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the SpinnerDateModel to specify the behavior. Below is an example in which the getNextValue and getPreviousValue are overridden to return values +/- 10 minutes:

```
    Date now = new Date();
    Date start = now;
    final long tenMinutesInMillis = 1000 * 60 * 10;
    Date end = new Date(now.getTime() + tenMinutesInMillis * 60);
    SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerDateModel(now, start, end, Calendar.MINUTE){
        @Override
        public Object getNextValue(){
            Date newDate = new Date(getDate().getTime() + tenMinutesInMillis);
            Date endDate = (Date)getEnd();
            return newDate.getTime() > endDate.getTime() ? endDate : newDate;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getPreviousValue(){
            Date newDate = new Date(getDate().getTime() - tenMinutesInMillis);
            Date startDate = (Date)getStart();
            return newDate.getTime() < startDate.getTime() ? startDate : newDate;
        }
    };
```

Comment: This doesn't do any range checking. The next/previous values should fall within the start/end range. Also, what if you want to increment by days?

Comment: Thanks - edited with range checking in mind. Just saw your answer and prefer it over this quick and dirty alternative (more flexible with the increment time).

Comment: I just copied the existing code from the `SpinnerDateModel` class and modified it to use a variable for the increment/decrement value. I try to avoid rewriting code when possible.